# Don't fix whats not broken

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have made code that stores utf-8 in a database.

It shows it well in the browser but looks distorted in the database. Since the functionality seems to work and it doesn't look like I have had any problems with processing the string input, is it any point in 'fixing what is not broken' and make utf-8 characters like Japanese show in the database?

I don't search the database since the strings are serialized anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "looks distorted in the database"?

Comment: How are you looking at the database? (Through what?)

Comment: What are you using to look inside your database? PhpMyAdmin or mysql console etc?

Comment: Hint: If they "show well in the browser" then the problem isn't in the database, it's with whatever you're using to look at the values.

Comment: Also, what collation are you using on the DB?

Comment: What do you mean with "show in the database"? Do you mean the command line `mysql` command?

Comment: i look at the database through a client. if I use `utf8_encode` etc. it shows as ??? otherwise as ÑÑ‚Ð² etc. I use charset utf-8, collaction utf8_general_ci

Comment: What client, specifically? I suspect you're using the `mysql` command in a terminal, and the charset for that console is not UTF-8.

Comment: using navicat and phpmyadmin. I have made the utf8 show in the database in another application i made earlier, but the technique doesn't work. i used `utf8_decode` before insert and `utf8_encode` on output, it worked fine.

Comment: Try viewing your data using the `mysql` client in a terminal; do you face the same problem?

Comment: If it looks wrong when viewing the database, doesn't that mean it is broken? More importantly, it's very likely that the wrong database settings are causing the incorrect display and may have negative effects on indices and such.

Comment: i know the database settings are correct because i always use this charset and collation. besides, i made a file earlier that saved utf-8 fine in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the text encoding of the queries, you are sending to MySQL with for instance

```
SET NAMES `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci`
```

If you don't, MySQL may interpret your query with the servers default text-encoding that can be different to UTF-8, e.g. iso-latin. So you will have strings in your tables, that are UTF-8 encoded, but MySQL marked them as iso-latin. That won't have much effect on your code, because MySQL just returns your UTF-8 strings back to you and you ignore the text-encoding. If you view the data in phpMyAdmin or any other application, that sets the connections character encoding, you will end up with distorted strings.

You could on the other hand `utf8_decode` your query strings and `utf8_encode` the result's provided by MySQL and don't change the connections text encoding from iso-latin. but if you query a different MySQL server that uses UTF-8 as default text encoding, you will end up with the same problem the other way around. so just set the connection's text encoding once after connecting.

Comment: where do i have to query for this? every time I connect?

Comment: every time you open a connection, you need to specify what encoding you are using with this connection. you could change the default for new connections on mysql's side.

Comment: here is some reference to read through for you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Seems this worked. Had never expected that, out of everything! (read about this many times before). Any advice on how to make this persistent so i dont have to call it all the time? Also, why does it matter if utf-8 shows in the database or not as long it shows properly in the code/HTML? is it because if it has to "guess what to send it back as", it might become trouble?

Comment: You can set the servers default text-encoding for connections to UTF-8, but in my opinion it's better to just send the `SET NAMES ... COLLATE ...` query on every connection. See the link above on how to change the default. MySQL does not guess the text encoding of strings in the database. the encoding is saved in the tables schematics. if you want put differently encoded strings into the tables, nothing is stopping you. but if you access tables not only through your own application or want your database be usable in the future, just handle the encoding the suggested way! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to access the database. If you use a console just the the encoding in the console to utf-8. If you use GUI software just check the options the set the encoding to utf-8. You can try 'set names' to ser the client encoding.